# How to retrieve subfolders and files from a folder in S3 bucket using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, etl

as I am quite new to loading from AWS S3 bucket i am facing some difficulties to query data from subfolders here is the steps and bucket description:

> Countries S3 bucket
>
> - subfolder for every extraction time e.g(2021-08-12 , 2021-08-11 ,...)
>
>   - each subfolder has the following:
>
>     - 2 sub-subfolders each contains json files that i need to query
>     - other json files also need to query

code produced so far:

```
s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
# Get bucket
bucket_name = "countries"
bucket = s3.Bucket(name=bucket_name)
path = "countries/"
```

##### 1- This steps fetches all the outer subfolders with extraction time

```
folders = []

client = boto3.client('s3')
result = client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=path, Delimiter='/')
for o in result.get('CommonPrefixes'):
    folders.append(o.get('Prefix'))
```

##### 2- Next iterate for every subfolder extract all the content inside

```
   for i in folders:
     sub = client.list_objects(Bucket = bucket_name , Prefix = folders[i] , Delimiter = '/')
```

##### 3- Next extract the jsons and subfolders , do all append or join

Currently i am failing with 2nd step as i pass `Prefix = folders[i]` while indexing by passing folders[0] returns the content of one subfolder from step 1, i am trying to iterate but get back this error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: The issue appears to be that `i` is not a loop counter, it's a reference to an item in the `folders` list. So instead of `Prefix = folders[i]`, use `Prefix = i`. Of course you may want to use a more descriptive variable name than `i`, but that's a stylistic issue.

Comment: Agreed! It would be much clearer to use `for folder in folders:` and then `Prefix = folder`. Using a counter in Python `for` loops is rarely needed (only for `range()` situations), and is typically done by people familiar with other languages bringing the shortcomings of those languages to their Python code.

Comment: thank you for this , really helped to iterate and also for the notes on styling the code, however with this iteration once i print(sub) inside the `for` loop it returns all, but if i print outside the for loop it returns only last "file/object or in this case folder", any thoughts why this is happening? @jscott @John

Comment: `sub` is not a list, it's just a reference to the value returned from the most recent call to `client.list_objects()`. So if you `print(sub)` after the `for` loop exits, you'll get the value that was assigned to `sub` in the last iteration of the `for` loop. If you want to keep track of all of the objects returned from each folder, you should declare `sub` as a list and append the `client.list_objects()` results, similar to how you handle the `folders` variable.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve as follows:

```
~~~copied from question~~~
s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
# Get bucket
bucket_name = "countries"
bucket = s3.Bucket(name=bucket_name)
path = "countries/"

~~~~~~

# Create a reusable Paginator
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')

# create list to store .json files
json_files = []

# Search thru each folder that was returned via path
def path_search(path_folders):
    for folder in path_folders:
        folder_search(folder)


def folder_search(folder):
    # get subfolders in folder
    list_objects_in_folder = client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=folder, Delimiter='/')
    
    #---- Looking for .json files -----
    
    # Create a PageIterator from the Paginator
    page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=folder, Delimiter='/')
    
    # Filter results for json files only. Can use JMESPath for other searches
    filtered_iterator = page_iterator.search("Contents[?ends_with(Key, '.json')][]")
    
    for key_data in filtered_iterator:
        if key_data != None:
            json_files.append(key_data['Key'])
        else:
            pass
    
    #-----------------------------------------------------------
    # get filepath for each item in the folder:
    try:
        for item in list_objects_in_folder.get("CommonPrefixes"):
            filepath = item.get("Prefix")
            # start the loop over again
            folder_search(filepath)
    except:
        # if folder is empty
        pass
```

This code will iterate thru every folder in a given path, look for .json files and subfolders, enter all subfolders, and repeat.

You can also find more help at these locations:

https://jmespath.org/examples.html

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_file